# How do i print one element of an arraylist to uppurcase while the other elements lowercase

Tags: java, arrays, oop, if-statement, arraylist

the elements of array list need to be printed one by one, which one be printed uppsercase other lowercase

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] days = {"monday","saturday","tuesday","sunday","friday"};
    ArrayList<String> weekdays = new ArrayList();
    weekdays.add("monday");
    weekdays.add("thursday");
    weekdays.add("wednesday");
    weekdays.add("surtaday");
    weekdays.add("tuesday");
    weekdays.add("sunday");
    weekdays.add("friday");

    // Loop through the ArrayList, printing out "sunday" elements in
    for(int i=0;i<weekdays.size();i++){     
        System.out.println(weekdays.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: ``if (weekdays.get(i).equals("sunday")) System.out.println(weekdays.get(i).toUpperCase());``

Answer (score 0):

Can you not add the word to the list as an uppercase letter? If not, depending on which word you want to capitalize, i'm assuming the first one, you can do this:

```
for(int i=0;i<weekdays.size();i++){

    if(i == 0){
      System.out.println(weekdays.get(i).toUpperCase());
    }else{
        System.out.println(weekdays.get(i));
    }

}
```

Similarily, if you want to do the second word:

```
  for(int i=0;i<weekdays.size();i++){

    if(i == 1){ //change this from 0 to 1
      System.out.println(weekdays.get(i).toUpperCase());
    }else{
        System.out.println(weekdays.get(i));
    }

}
```

and so on...
You need to change the value in the if statement depending on the word you want to capitalize